# How to pass JSON value to component with interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm beginning to learn typescript react and don't know to how to correctly pass JSON variable from API call to component with interface.

```js
export default function App() {
  const [calendarData, setCalendarData] = useState<ICalendarProps>();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const url = Constants.API_URL_GET_AVAILABLE;
    const data = {
      date: encodeURIComponent('2023-03-01'),
      period: encodeURIComponent(30),
      duration: encodeURIComponent(30),
    }

    await fetch(url + `?Date=${data.date}&Period=${data.period}&Duration=${data.duration}`, {
      method: 'GET'
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(postsFromServer => {
        console.log(postsFromServer);
        setCalendarData(postsFromServer);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <CalendarView data={calendarData} /> {/* <--- here i get error  */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I get an error like this

```
TS2322: Type 'ICalendarProps | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ Date: string; Availables: number; Terms: ITerm; }'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ Date: string; Availables: number; Terms: ITerm; }'.
```

The component I'm trying to pass a variable to looks like this

```js
export default function CalendarView(props: ICalendarProps) {
    const [data, setData] = useState(props.data);
    return <div></div>;
}
```

And custom interface

```js
export interface ICalendarProps {
  data: {
    Date: string;
    Availables: number;
    Terms: ITerm;
  }
}
export interface ITerm {
  Time: string;
  Duration: number;
  IsOccupied: number;
  IsVisible: number;
}
```

I was trying to initialize variable which im trying to pass. Also trying to return after fetching data but dont know how. There must be sth im missing out. Is this correct way of writing react?

Comment: You could also add `v-if="calendarView"` directive to `<div>` that wraps `CalendarView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The Problem

The fundamental reason for error is that `CalendarView` component has types for props as `ICalendarProps` which is a **required** prop.

On top of that the types of state variable and prop *do not match*. (explained in next section)

However, if you see in `App` component, we have

```js
<CalendarView data={calendarData} />
```

which is referencing `calendarData` to pass to `data` field in props.

This `calendarData` is a variable de-structured from return of `useState` as

```js
const [calendarData, setCalendarData] = useState<ICalendarProps>();
```

As you can see, the initial state is `undefined` and hence, you get the error because a possible `undefined` variable is being passed to `data` prop which is supposed to be of some defined type.

#### The fix

I think the type for state variable needs to update, let me use the below defined interface to solve it.

```js
interface IData {
    Date: string;
    Availables: number;
    Terms: ITerm;
}

const [calendarData, setCalendarData] = useState<IData>();
```

1. One of the most basic fixes will be to update `ICalendarProps` as

```js
interface ICalendarProps {
  data?: IData;
}
```

This is marking `data` as optional and will work fine.

2. Another approach will be to supply a default variable of the type

```js
const defaultData: IData = {
    Date: '',
    Availables: 0,
    Terms: {
          Time: '',
          Duration: 0,
          IsOccupied: 0,
          IsVisible: 0
    }
}
...
<CalendarView data={calendarData || defaultData} />
...
```

3. You may also try assigning an initial value to the state to resolve this with the above defined `defaultData`

```js
const [calendarData, setCalendarData] = useState<IData>(defaultData);
```

Comment: You could also add condition in the template

`<div v-if="calendarView"> <CalendarView ... /> </div>`